# How do I update my local Git origin vs. upstream settings?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have been following [this guide](https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/how-to-migrate-a-private-repository-from-bitbucket-to-github-6cddedd5d73) to migrate my BitBucket repos over to GitHub.

Specifically, I'm creating the new GitHub repo, and then setting that as an upstream on my local Git config like this.

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com:USER/PROJECT.git
git push upstream master
git push --tags upstream
```

This works as expected, but it leaves me with origin set at BitBucket and upstream set at GitHub.

[image]

At this point I would prefer GitHub to be my origin and BitBucket to be my upstream.  How can I easily swap these?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rename each.  You'll need an intermediate name to avoid stepping on one while doing the rename dance:

```
git remote rename upstream foo
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote rename foo origin
```

and you're done.  (Just make sure `foo` is not the name of yet another remote.)